# Get a 2D concave polygon from a 3D object

Tags: c++, 3d, box2d, vertex, bounding-box

I am currently running out of time for my 3D project, so I've decided to give all of the physics and collisions to Box2D *since my project would only use 2d collisions, but have 3D graphics*.

The Box2D world would be topdown, so I need to take my 3D object and **flatten** it into a 2D polygon. This is as easy as removing the y coordinate from each vertex, but Box2D would not like a bunch of vertices overlapping the actual object:

[image: A 3D object]
[image: Topdown object (flattened)]

So I would like some advice on how could I implement an **algorithm (or is there a library that I should use?)** to get a nice pretty polygon like this:

[image: Nice pretty polygon]

**or is generating an OOBB easier?**

**EDIT:** I now realize that Box2D only takes convex shapes! But this could still be useful for other libraries with more precise physics.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculating a 2D representation of a 3D object, one possible approach is rasterization: You create a binary raster image of your object from a top view ("binary" meaning that each pixel is only black or white), and then you either use the set of black pixels as your 2D object representation, or if you still want a polygon, you run a boundary traversal algorithm to calculate the sequence of pixels that make the boundary of this 2D object. The precision of this algorithm is determined by the pixel resolution. One such implementation is OpenCV's findContours (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html).

Once you have a sequence of pixels, you might want to simplify the polyline, to keep the vertex count low, so that subsequent operations with this polyline will run faster. (see http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyline_simplification_2/index.html)

---

More generally, if you're doing collisions, you need to start by deciding how precise you need the collision detection to be. If you want high precision 3D collision detection, then flattening to 2D is not a good approach. So, if you need high precision and high performance, you have to do some preprocessing on your mesh, like calculating a hierarchical tree of axis-aligned bounding boxes or bounding spheres (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy). If your objects undergo rigid transformations, then bounding spheres are good because a sphere remains a sphere under rigid transformations, where as bounding boxes don't remain axis-aligned after rotating them.

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking so long to reply. Looks awesome! But I now realize that I didn't really write what I wanted. I know that getting outilne vertices of a concave shape is really complicated, and rasterizing seems like the best solution, but Box2D only accepts convex shapes. This was obviously my fault and I drew my monkey outline as a concave shape!

I'll leave this here for future reference and a good answer, but I might ask another question for getting a convex shape out of this (think, wrapping a tight elastic around the shape).